# How do I make Java protocol buffer types mutable? Protoc.exe doesn't generate setters?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

How do I make Java protocol buffer types mutable?

Protoc.exe doesn't generate setters?

Basically I need to create an object then change a field value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't the intended usages of the library; you would set the values at the builder stage, then create the immutable DTO from the builder. If you want different values: change the value in the builder and regenerate the DTO.

Alternatively, note that there are multiple libraries providing support for the protobuf wire specification. IIRC "protostuff" works with mutable POJO objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use builders everywhere where you still want objects to be mutable. They have both getters and setters.

Comment: I never thought of that, even after a couple of years working with Java protobufs and C++ protobufs and complaining about the philosophical differences between them.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you can't do this with the standard protoc tool and the standard generator plugin.

AFAIK, your only option is to write your own generator (or modify the existing one) to do what you need.

Alternatively, you could use "nasty" reflection tricks to reach into the objects and modify the state that way.

(Why do you feel that you need to change field values after creating objects?  Can't you just change the field value in the builder and call `build` again?)